# How to use recursion for a sub set problem in C

Tags: recursion, dynamic

I am a beginner trying to teach myself C and I had a problem the other day which I thought would be cool to try and solve with a short program. I found it a bit more difficult to solve than I initially thought. Basically the problem goes like this.

I want to be able to enter a single int value between 0..255 (never outside this range) into a function, and inside the function there is an array of 8 values (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128), which can be combined by adding together to get reach the single int value. And then return the different combinations possible. i.e.

Target 192

Returns
64, 128

From what I have read this is a sub set problem and can be solved with recursion, but I am really struggling to put the theory and examples I've found into practice. If someone could help me out or even put me in the right direction to try and solve.

Comment: You say you want "the different combinations possible", but are you sure you want more than one solution? I would assume you only want the (unique) solution which uses only value once. For instance, `192 = 128 + 32 + 32`, but I assume you don't want that solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all, it's a good idea to keep I/O and algorithms separated. So you generally shouldn't design functions which take user input *and* performs some algorithm at the same time.

Next up "can be solved with recursion" is not a goal of it's own. Recursion is dangerous, inefficient and hard to read. There exists very few cases where it should be used in C programming and no cases where beginners should use it at all. Most of the time, recursion in C simply boils down to: "I could paint this barn while standing on my hands at the same time"... well maybe you could, maybe you could do it without risk breaking your neck, maybe you can even do it as quickly as if you were standing upright (not likely), but *why* would you do it?

Program design aside, the algorithm you are looking for is closely related to binary numbers. Any number in any base can be formed by:

digit<sub>n</sub> * base<sup>n</sup> + digit<sub>n-1</sub> * base<sup>n-1</sup>... + digit<sub>0</sub> * base<sup>0</sup>.

In case of binary (base 2) numbers manually, for example 111 can be manually decoded to decimal as:

1 * 2<sup>2</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>1</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>0</sup> = 4 + 2 + 1 decimal = 7 decimal.

Now if we compare this with your algorithm, the multipliers above for base 2 correspond to 1, 2, 4, 8...

Conveniently, all numbers in C are actually raw binary. They only get translated to other bases when doing user input/output. So what you need for your algorithm is simply a way to check individual digits of a binary number are set or not.

This can be done with the `&` "bitwise AND" and `<<` "bitwise left shift" operators. The bitwise left shift to shift the value 1 left to get the various multipliers: 0b=0, 1b=1, 10b=2, 100b=4 and so on. And then bitwise AND to mask out an individual bit from the rest, to see if it is set or not. If it isn't set, well then by the above formula we get 0*base<sup>n</sup> for that digit, so it will be zero and can be ignored.

Writing the actual C code for that is actually quite easy:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  unsigned int mask = 1u << i; 
  if(mask & number)
  {
    printf("%u\n", mask);
  }
}
```

(This is using unsigned numbers to avoid various common bugs, but that's a topic of its own.)

Comment: I think the OP wanted to learn about recursion and arithmetic, and instead this answer is telling them to forget arithmetic and recursion, and use bitwise operators and loops. Your code is certainly more efficient, and loops and bitwise operators are worth studying, but if the OP is studying recursion and arithmetic operators at this moment, this is a bit off-topic for them.

Comment: @Stef I'm assuming they want to become a good programmer. If someone wants to learn how to paint barns while standing on their hands, I ought to teach them: don't do that, it's silly, dangerous and inefficient and there's absolutely nothing gained from it. Do it as quick and simple as possible, by standing upright. Don't practice bad habits or you'll start using the bad habits to make bad programs.

Comment: A good programmer should understand the similarities and differences between using `/` and `%` and using `<<` and `&`. But they won't, if they don't learn about `/` and `%` first. Also, your statement "recursion is dangerous, inefficient and hard to read" is misleading, in my opinion. Loops can be dangerous, inefficient and hard to read too. A good way to avoid writing dangerous code is to actually learn about code, rather than be told "don't learn this it's like standing on your hands".

Comment: Incidentally, after several years of experience I have developed the opinion that students who learn about recursion first and loops second usually end up writing much better code than students who learn about loops first and recursion second. Recursion is actually much more natural than loops. Many people "fear" recursion and start thinking irrationally when recursion is involved, because they learned about loops first. This is all very counterintuitive, when recursion follows human logic so much more naturally.

Comment: @Stef The issue is that you should not learn about recursion _at all_ because it should pretty much never be used. The main issues being the stack peak usage and blocking out compiler optimizations. It's very important to have code which doesn't cause stack overflows or execute dreadfully slow. While the counter argument "it feels more natural" is subjective nonsense. Make programs that are safe and fast, period.

Comment: As for when recursion should be used, I can only come up with one very narrow example. And that is when manually optimizing a BST or similar to reduce overall RAM consumption (by removing parent pointers from being saved in the data structure), at the cost of peak RAM consumption and potentially slower execution. That's a very specialized scenario. I can't think of any other case where it makes sense.

Comment: Recursion is generally more natural and easier to read than loops. That said, because C is not guaranteed to correctly handle tail calls, you are correct that if performance is essential, one should avoid using recursion in C. There are situations, however, when recursion can be higher-performance than iteration - for example, when performing mutating operations on a red-black tree, where you're guaranteed that the recursion depth will be small and the alternative is using a heap-allocated stack.

Comment: @MarkSaving If you give each node a parent pointer and execute in a plain loop, the ADT will almost certainly be faster than the recursive version even if tail call optimization and unrolling was achieved. Which is rarely the case in BST, because you typically always have one call for the left node and one for the right, and compilers will struggle to optimize that.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: try the "bitwise and" operator (`&`)